# Cockroachdb: Retrieving cluster info: failed Error: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I am trying to connect to my Cockroachdb cluster using:

```
ccloud auth login && \
ccloud cluster sql ocean-panda
```

To which I am getting the following error:

```
logged in to "YASH KOTHARI's Organization" (org-3447v) as YASH KOTHARI
Retrieving cluster info: failed
Error: 401 Unauthorized
2022/11/02 17:58:59 401 Unauthorized
```

Therefore, it is logging into my account, but not giving me access to any of my clusters. What to do? Did I mess up any certificates or something? I have tried to remove and reinstall anything cockroachdb related but nothing is working. I tried to do this on someone else's system and it is working fine. I am getting this error just on my system!
I am on a Mac (M1) btw.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a ton for sharing this, we're currently testing some new connection flows using the `ccloud` CLI and this is a new one!

I'm going to look into it on our side, since this looks like a bug. In the meantime I'd recommend using the other connection options that are available. They can be reached using the "Connect" button in the cluster overview page.

A few other steps that could potentially get it working:

- `ccloud auth logout && ccloud auth login` to refresh the login parameters
- `ccloud cluster list` and see if the same error occurs

[image: cluster overview page]

Comment: It was probably an artifact, it is working now..

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to message with any other questions/feedback here or on the CockroachDB Slack channel :)

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/join-community/